# (Newbie question) Something goes wrong here with db_add_field

Tags: 7, entities, hooks

I'm trying to adapt that [D6 module](http://www.heididev.com/how-get-node-visits-accesslog) to D7.
I'm on the "add afield" part of .install

Here's my code :

```
function node_statistics_install() {
    db_add_field('accesslog', 'nid', array(
    'description' => 'Field added by node_statistics',
    'type' => 'int',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'unsigned' => TRUE,
    'length' => 11,
    'default' => 0,
  ));
```

but nothing happens in the database on install, no errors in drupal logs...
Am I missing something?

Comment: have you reviewed http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!database!database.inc/function/db_add_field/7

Comment: check if accesslog table exists in your database.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure that **Statistics** module installed/enabled.

Second, replace your code with the following code:

```
function node_statistics_schema_alter(&$schema) {
  // Add field to existing schema.
  $schema['accesslog']['fields']['nid'] = array(
    'type' => 'int',
    'length' => '11',
    'default' => '0',
    'not null' => TRUE,
    'unsigned' => TRUE,  
    'description' => 'Field added by node_statistics',
  ); 
}

function node_statistics_install() { 
  $table = 'accesslog';

  $schema = drupal_get_schema($table);

  db_add_field($table, 'nid', $schema['fields']['nid']);
}
```

Note: make sure to uninstall and install your module after you apply the new code.